# Sizing container for AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to camera aspect ratio

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, camera

How can I adjust the height of a container for a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer such that it won't be cropped? For instance:

```
let cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
cameraPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect //or .resizeAspectFill
cameraPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
cameraPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.frame
view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer, at: 0)
```

- resizeAspectFill preserves the aspect ratio at the expense of cropping the preview image.
- resizeAspect shows the preview without cropping, but just centres the feed and leaves bars at the top/bottom

Instead, I want the container itself to adjust it's own dimensions, so the parent view can re-flow accordingly instead. If I had the aspect ratio, then I'd be able to do this, but I can't see a way to obtain that.

Does anyone have any sugggestions?

Comment: You could use `func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {` to get the `sampleBuffer`, which you can convert to `CIImage` (`CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!)`). Then you can read the `extent`, which is a CGSize.

Comment: There's probably a better way though